# Changing color of headline if width is under 600 doesn't work

Tags: html, css

My problem is that it doesn't change the color if the width is under 600px. Here is my code:
`

```
    /* Add a headline */
      .top-bar h1 {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 15px;
      font-size: 50px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: white;
    }
  
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
    .top-bar h1 {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 15px;
      font-size: 50px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: red;
    }
  }
```

`
The media somehow doesn't get triggered.

If I just leave it like that the headline is always white and doesn't change it's color.

Comment: either add !important to color: red
or add @media (min-width: 600px) to the first class

Comment: I added @media (min-width: 600px) but still doesn't work.

Comment: I prefer to use media in other way: small to top. First I define the smallest in the class, media min-width:600px when it's bigger than 600... and so on, that's easily readable

Comment: I posted my answer with the spy on the viewport width in real time to show the conditions while running. By the way at this point I also suspect you might be mistakenly consider the selector `.top-bar h1`. That means an `h1` element as (direct or indirect) child of an element having the class `top-bar`. I'm sure you got it right already but since you didn't include the html it's legit to have the doubt

Comment: Are you tessting on an actual mobile device or only on your browser dev tools?

Comment: Have you got a meta viewport tag in your head element? This enables emulators to pick up the right width.  e.g.  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you actually meant because your code seems working.

Anyway I crafted a snippet here with the evidence of the viewport size refresh on window resize, to show the correct working of the media query.

If you open the responsive mode in your browser, you'll see the style changing in real time.. and when the viewport width will be <= 500px the headline color will remain red and will turn black when the size will be bigger.

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
  refreshViewportSize();
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    refreshViewportSize();
});

const refreshViewportSize = ()=>{
  const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);
  const vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0);
  document.getElementById('viewportsize')
    .innerText = `w: ${vw}`;
  //.innerText = `${vw}x${vw}`;
}
```

```css
h1.top-bar {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .top-bar h1 {
    color: red;
  }
}

#viewportsize{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  border: solid red;
  font-size: 3rem;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: .25rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar">
  <h1>Headline</h1>
</div>

<div id="viewportsize"></div>
```